# Deduplicate numpy array by another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3])
b = np.array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0])
```

`a` is the index of items, and `b` is the score of corresponding items. Now I want to sort these items **descendingly** by the scores in `b` while **only keeping the largest score** of a single item. The results should be the non-duplicated item index `a_new` and the score of these items `b_new`.

In the example above, I need:

```
a_new = np.array([3, 0, 2, 1])
b_new = np.array([1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6])
```

I know I can do this with `scatter_max` however it's a little slow. Is there any easier and faster solutions?

Note that I don't want to transform the array to a dictionary, which is a trivial solution. I need a batched solution because I have millions of such arrays.

Comment: "A batched solution" means I can process multiple array-pairs in batch.

Comment: I think I can sort the array, then apply np.unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After ordering the arrays in descending order using `ordering`, repeated values could be removed by `np.unique`:

```
ordering = np.argsort(b)[::-1]
a = a[ordering]
b = b[ordering]
undup_ind = np.unique(a, return_index=True)[1]
b = b[np.sort(undup_ind)]
```

This will be the fastest or one of the fastest ways to reach the goal; It ran in 0.5 seconds in my tested case by 1.000.000 data volume.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with pandas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3])
b = np.array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.stack([a, b], axis=1), columns = ['a', 'b'])
df = df.groupby('a')['b'].max().to_frame().reset_index().sort_values(by=['b'], ascending=False)

a_new = df['a'].to_numpy()
b_new = df['b'].to_numpy()
```

If you want parallel processing, can explore PySpark, Dask, and alike.